# How to float blocks of undetermined width

Tags: css, css-float, overflow

I am having problems floating multiple DIVs, allowing them to bust out of acontaining div.  Please see my code below as an example.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-GB">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style>
            * {
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
                box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
            }

            div.outer {
                width:300px;
                height:300px;
                border:3px solid #000;
                overflow:visible;
                padding:10px;
            }

            div.mid {
                overflow:hidden;
                border:1px solid #000;
                padding:0;
                width:485px;;
            }

            div.inner {
                width:150px;
                height:100px;
                background:#EDEDED;
                border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
                float:left;
                margin:5px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body class="landingPage">
        <div class="outer">
            <div class="mid">
                <div class="inner"></div>
                <div class="inner"></div>
                <div class="inner"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This works fine, but in reality, i will not know how many "inner" DIVs there will be, nor how wide they are. Therefore, I cannot place the "width" property in the div.mid CSS. However, whenever I remove the width, the inner DIVs wrap.

Can anyone help? Unfortunately, the box-sizing property must remain

[here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LZ8rZ/)

Comment: Should the inner div's burst out of the parent? Or not? Should there appear a scrollbar, or should the parent div stretch, or should the inner div be shown on a new line?

Comment: do you need the outer div's with fixed and inner div's should be contained within the div?

Comment: The inner DIVs should not bust out of the parent div and they should all be on one line, so the parent DIV should expand to fit them.  I do not want scrollbars. I should also mention that it is possible for the "mid" div to be wider than the browser window. Inner DIVs should still remain on one line, even though they are out of view.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the inner `div` and set `width: auto;` and `max-width: 150px;` if you know that has to be the most but you don't know what size they'll be.

Comment: No, I do not know the widths at all. It is quite possible for an inner div to be wider than the browser window, especially if viewed on a mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I try do a few things when i have to encapsulate content of  unknown size:

1. use max-width in addition to width
2. use percentages instead of fixed widths for anything that's inside.
3. try box-sizing: content-box instead of border-box.